# gorm [error] unsupported data type: &map[]

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to create an API using `map`, but when in models I define map type, it error with message not support

**This is Model**

```
type Movie struct {
    ID          int            `json:"id" validate:"number"`
    Title       string         `json:"title"`
    Description string         `json:"description"`
    Year        int            `json:"year"`
    ReleaseDate time.Time      `json:"release_date"`
    Runtime     int            `json:"runtime"`
    Rating      int            `json:"rating"`
    MPAARating  string         `json:"mpaa_rating"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time      `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time      `json:"updated_at"`
    MovieGenres map[int]string `json:"-" gorm:"many2many:movie_genres"`
}

type Genre struct {
    ID        int       `json:"-"`
    GenreName string    `json:"genre_name"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
}

type MovieGenre struct {
    ID        int       `json:"id"`
    MovieID   int       `json:"movie_id"`
    GenreID   int       `json:"genre_id"`
    Genre     Genre     `gorm:"foreignKey:GenreID"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"-"`
}
```

**and this is the code to retrieve data by ID**

```
func (MovieRepositoryImpl *MovieRepositoryImpl) GetMovieById(id int) (*Movie, error) {
    var movie Movie
    err := MovieRepositoryImpl.DB.First(&movie, id).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var movie_genres MovieGenre
    rows, err := MovieRepositoryImpl.DB.Model(&movie_genres).Preload(movie_genres.Genre.GenreName).Rows()
    defer rows.Close()

    genres := make(map[int]string)
    for rows.Next() {
        err := MovieRepositoryImpl.DB.ScanRows(rows, &movie_genres).Error

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        genres[movie_genres.ID] = movie_genres.Genre.GenreName
    }

    movie.MovieGenres = genres

    return &movie, nil
}
```

**This is my Expect**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73589270/how-add-map-to-struct-in-golang

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `MovieGenres map[int]string` to `MovieGenres datatypes.JSONMap`

- https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html
- https://github.com/go-gorm/datatypes/blob/master/json_map.go